# get EntityManager from a constraint in symfony

Tags: symfony

the thing is that I'm creating a custom validator and in my new validator class I should do something like this:

```
class EmailDoesntExistValidator extends ConstraintAValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); // ERROR!!!!!!!
        $result = $em->getRepository('CgboardSignupBundle:User')->userExist($value);

        if (empty($result)) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Im having this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cgboard\SignupBundle\Validator\Constraints\EmailDoesntExistValidator::getDoctrine()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you need to inject the EntityManager / Doctrine dependency.

Read here how to create validators with dependencies:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies